# Como tratas en JavaScript un dato desde PHP

Tags: php, javascript

Tengo una tabla donde una celda contiene una imagen, la cual al ser clickeada ejecutara una función encargada de abrir un cuadro `dialog` con la imagen en grande.

```
<td style="width: 20%;"><?php
$source = $row['T_IMG'];
echo "<img width='50px' height='50px' src=".$source." onclick='maximizeImg()'> "; 
?></td>
```

Mi duda es, si le mando `maximizeImg(".$source.")` para que la función reciba la imagen adecuada de cada fila, en la función:

```
function maximizeImg(){
                var table = document.getElementById('tableRelatedTest');
                var rCount = table.rows.length;;
                //alert(table.rows[rCount - 1].cells[14].innerHTML);
                var sourceImg = table.rows[rCount - 1].cells[14].innerHTML;
                document.getElementById("imageMax").src = sourceImg;
                $(function () {
                            $("#dialog1").dialog();
                            $("#dialog1").show();
                        });
                        return;
            }
```

Como recojo o trato ese `String` en la función para que así se asigne la imagen de cada fila correctamente, de esa forma me podría quitar el `rCount-1` que tengo indicado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No hace falta enviar el `source` que obtiene desde `PHP` para acceder a la imagen , para este ejemplo bastaría pasar la palabra reservada `this`. Para que luego desde JavaScript acceda a ese elemento que llegará como parámetro *(img) para el ejemplo*

**PHP**

```
echo "<img width='50px' height='50px' src=".$source." onclick='maximizeImg(this)'> ";
```

**JS**

```
function maximizeImg(img){
  document.getElementById("imageMax").src = img.src;
}
```